# Create a multiframe .tif file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have pixel data that I want to use to create a new `.tif` image that has multiple frames. How would I go about doing this? I have tried python PIL however I have only found it supports multiple frame reading not writing. See below for my attempt that didn't work.

```
new_Image = Image.new("I;16", (num_pixels,num_rows))

for frame in range((len(final_rows)/num_rows)):
    pixels = new_Image.load()
    for row in range(num_rows):
        row_pixel = final_rows[row].getPixels()
        for pixel in range(num_pixels):
            pixels[pixel,row] = row_pixel[pixel]
    print frame
    new_Image.seek(frame)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, using numpy and [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) with [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) plugin:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io._plugins import freeimage_plugin as fi
image = np.zeros((32, 256, 256), 'uint16')
fi.write_multipage(image, 'multipage.tif')
```

Or save it uncompressed using numpy and [tifffile.py](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html):

```
import numpy as np
from tifffile import imsave
image = np.zeros((32, 256, 256), 'uint16')
imsave('multipage.tif', image)
```

This assumes that all pages have the same data shape and type and no additional tags need to be written.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'skimage.io._plugins.freeimage_plugin' has no attribute 'write_multipage'