# Custom file structure to save multiple images in python

Tags: python

I am experimenting with packaging of data, and since most of my data is stored as image/graphs and other similar data; I was planning to find a more efficient way to store these images.

I did read about saving them in a DB as blob; and some others are more inclined to save them in the file system; but what I would like is to have the images to not be visible outside the application. This is essential because when I run analysis on instruments; I am not interested in showing users all the images, but only the ones related to their particular instrument.
Plus it is convenient to pack data in one single file, compared to a folder with 20-30 images in it.

I was thinking to store the images in a custom structure, a sort of a bin file, using python; unless there is something that already cover that functionality. In my search I didn't notice any specific struct to save images, while the most common solutions were either a folder in the file system or the DB approach.

Comment: can't you use normal .zip file ? Python has standard module [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and [other compressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html)

Comment: You could perhaps use pandas and store the images in a Panel: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html 
then just save the data structure to disk.
Or you could perhaps go with a TIFF stack:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544568/create-a-multiframe-tif-file

Comment: Zip file may work, after all I can just extract a specific image in temp and display it in the app

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your images to raster arrays, you can store them in an HDF5 file: [Add raster image to HDF5 file using h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724553/add-raster-image-to-hdf5-file-using-h5py)